# What framework for hosting web app in mobile app, alternatives to Cordova

Tags: android, ios, mobile, architecture, frameworks

I have a mobile web app written in Bootstrap that I would like to release as a native app for iOS/Android. I was planning on using Apache Cordova as a wrapper, but this is no longer supported by iOS/Android. I don't need any native functionality, I just want the app to behave exactly as the web app does.

What is the best alternative wrapper framework?